# How to get all versions of row by rowKey and filters (HBase)?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I put a entity with 3CF

```
    Put entity = new Put(id.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    HashMap<String, String> keyFields = new HashMap<>();
    keyFields.put("MessageOperation", applicationEntity.getMessageOperation());

    String key = gson.toJson(keyFields);

    entity.addColumn(M, META, meta.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    entity.addColumn(K, KEYS, key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    entity.addColumn(D, BODY, body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I try to get BODY by id(format of id like "10:3331-333333-333333") and filters by KEYS.

```
        Get gett = new Get(id.getBytes());
        ArrayList<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        if (messageOperation != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(messageOperation)) {
            Filter filterByMsgOp = new SingleColumnValueFilter(K, KEYS, CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                    new SubstringComparator("\"MessageOperation\":\"" + messageOperation));
            filters.add(filterByMsgOp);
        }
        FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, filters);
        gett.setFilter(filterList);
        gett.setMaxVersions(5);
        gett.setTimeRange(0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        entity = table.get(gett);
        NavigableMap<byte[], byte[]> data = entity.getFamilyMap(D);
        String resultt = new String(data.get(BODY));
```

This works, but if i put two rows with the same id but different KEYS then I can only get the last entry.

if I put in the shell `scan 'emp', {VERSIONS=>4}`
I see all bodies. How to get BODY by id and filters?